# Runtime error '1004' with this specific code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the code below.

The code is written with the purpose of calculating the varians of a randomly constructed portfolio of different assets.
The problem occurs when I try to calculate the varians, and what troubles me is that the code works outside the loops.

This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
Sub kovariansmatrice()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim Var As Long
Dim k, j As Integer
Dim Random As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fifth As Double
Dim varians As Variant

For k = 1 To 1571 Step 10
    Cells(2, 1573) = k

    For j = 1 To 5000
        For i = 1 To 1571
            Randomize 
            Random = Rnd(1)
            Worksheets("Kovarians").Cells(3, i).Value = Random
        Next i

        Fifth = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A3:BHK3"), k)
        Worksheets("Kovarians").Cells(5, 1).Value = Fifth

        Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"), Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A11:BHK1581")), Application.Transpose(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"))) = varians
        Worksheets("Kovarians").Cells(5, 3).Value = varians

        Calculate
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, k) = Sheets("Kovarians").Cells(5, 3)

    Next j
Next k

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Below is a sub which is included in the above code. This sub-code works without any problems.

```
Sub Prove()

Dim Random As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim Fifth As Double
Dim varians As Variant

For i = 1 To 1571
    Randomize 
    Random = Rnd(1)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, i).Value = Random
Next i

Fifth = WorksheetFunction.Large(Range("A3:BHK3"), 5)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 1).Value = Fifth

varians = Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Range("A2:BHK2"), Range("A11:BHK1581")), Application.Transpose(Range("A2:BHK2")))
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 1).Value = varians

End Sub
```

In advance, thank you for your time.

Comment: What line shows the error?

Comment: Hi Ron
it's this line where the error occurs; Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"), Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A11:BHK1581")), Application.Transpose(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"))) = varians
        Worksheets("Kovarians").Cells(5, 3).Value = varians

Comment: You are showing two lines.  Perhaps the two sides of the first line should be reversed, as they are in your functioning subcode.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is occuring because of the `=` order on the specified line.  Instead of

```
Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"), Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A11:BHK1581")), Application.Transpose(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"))) = varians
```

the code should be

```
varians = Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2"), Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A11:BHK1581")), Application.Transpose(Sheets("Kovarians").Range("A2:BHK2")))
```

Comment: Hi RGA

This doesn't help with the error unfortunately.

Comment: @KristianNielsen what error is thrown with that change?

Comment: The code actually runs now but I just get #VALUE where the variance should be (cell(5,3)).

Comment: @KristianNielsen then I would guess you have invalid data somewhere within the range being matrix multiplied

Comment: I found the problem and it was because the range was wrong specified.

Now I get the message "Code execution has been interrupted"

Comment: @KristianNielsen do you have a break point set in your code? [check this link for a solution](http://www.businessprogrammer.com/code-execution-has-been-interrupted/)

Comment: Following the link seemed to work!!
Thank you for your help RGA!!